# Does Devil's Fruit power gained depend on how much of it is eaten?

Tags: one-piece

Luffy accidentally ate the Gomu-Gomu (Rubber-Rubber) fruit, but was interrupted by Shanks after a few bites. It was too late and Luffy got the Devil's Fruit powers anyway. If he had instead eaten the whole of it, would he have got even more power from the fruit?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the One Piece wiki, it's stated, that it doesn't matter, how much someone eats.

> Only one bite is needed for the user to gain the power of a Devil Fruit, after which the Devil Fruit becomes a simple, useless, disgusting fruit. Swallowing the fruit whole, as Buggy did, has the same effect,[8] as well as peeling off the skin and eating it piece by piece also works.

However, that is never stated in the manga/anime.

[Source](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit)

Answer (score 0):

When a Devil Fruit eater eats another Devil Fruit, the Devil within the second fruit kills him, be it a single bite or the whole fruit. This shows that only a small part of the fruit is required to gain the power.