# Can multiple people/animal eat a single Devil Fruit?

Tags: one-piece

Provided, Chopper eats the Devil Fruit along with the other deers, will they all have the Devil Fruit ability, given that acquiring the ability only requires a single bite?

Comment: Possible Duplicate or just related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/906/does-devils-fruit-power-gained-depend-on-how-much-of-it-is-eaten

Comment: But there are people who ate the same fruit in the anime, like the 2 sisters from the maiden island they both possess the Snake-Snake power, and the Tontatta tribe there is a boy and girl who both have the Bug-Bug power.

Comment: Those are different fruits. They just fall within the same animal race, but are still different animals. With the sisters, you have the [King cobra](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hebi_Hebi_no_Mi,_Model:_King_Cobra) fruit and the [Anaconda](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hebi_Hebi_no_Mi,_Model:_Anaconda) fruit. With the Tontatta you would have the [Rhinoceros beetle](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mushi_Mushi_no_Mi,_Model:_Kabutomushi) fruit and the [Giant Hornet](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mushi_Mushi_no_Mi,_Model:_Suzumebachi) fruit.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [One Piece wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit):

> Only one bite is needed for the user to gain the power of a Devil Fruit, after which the Devil Fruit becomes a simple, useless, disgusting fruit

So I would say that the answer is no. Only one person/animal gets the ability.

Comment: out of curiosity, if two people eat half by half together, What will happen ??

Comment: @NaingLinAung Whoever takes the first bite gets the power. There will always be someone who swallowed first, if not by a millisecond, than by a microsecond.

Answer (score 3):

When a Devil Fruit is bitten (even once), it loses its powers PERMANENTLY or until the person who bit it first dies. When the person who first bit it dies, the Devil Fruit returns to its normal state, so someone else can get the power. If Luffy died (what a sad thought!) then the Gum Gum fruit would be able to give someone else Gum Gum powers. So only one person at a time can have its power, not more than one.

Comment: Wait, so if some kept half of the Gum Gum fruit (Luffy only ate half in this theory), then killed Luffy, the other half would re-gain its power?

Comment: @ShadowZorgon No, because that half comes from the same fruit it would already have lost it's powers. The Gum Gum fruit would 'respawn' in another closeby fruit (without powers)