# What happens if a Devil Fruit is destroyed?

Tags: one-piece

We know that if a Devil Fruit user dies, their fruit reappears (see [In One Piece, does a Devil Fruit reappear after the user dies?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2979/24)). However, this doesn't answer the question of what happens when the fruit gets destroyed without being eaten. I don't know if that's even possible, but I imagine so with sufficient effort.

If a devil fruit is destroyed, would the fruit reincarnate in a nearby fruit (the same as when the user dies), or would it be destroyed for good?

Comment: The answer is likely to be something like, whatever destroys it will gain the power. Spandam's sword which "ate" the Elephant fruit comes to mind. Oda is known for his "creative" explanations, so anything is possible.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can separate destroyed and *being eaten*, eating a devil fruit in One Piece pretty much [*destroys*](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/932/1528) it. So destruction by power, physical force and or being eaten could be considered as being the same.

That being said, I would think the same thing would happen in any instance of it being *'destroyed'*, it will *'respawn'* and take on the form of it's closest *'relative'*.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying, but I think you're falling into a [fallacy of affirming the consequent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent). It is true that eating a Devil Fruit destroys it, and it will respawn after the user dies. However, that doesn't say anything about what happens if a fruit is destroyed in some other way. As for whether it respawns, I'm looking for some solid canonical evidence for this, not just speculation, because this was already a possibility I acknowledged in my question.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can get a canon answer is from the source. Yet, seeing as there is no way to just *destroy* anything, this situation is completely void, since it would never happen, and would have no reason to.

Since canon won't happen, here's some speculation: Since nothing can be destroyed, whatever remains of the fruit (and there *will* be remains) will be eaten by bacterium. After the bacteria dies, the fruit will be reborn. So, I guess iKlsR was as right as you could hope for.

Answer (score -1):

This question has been already answered here:

[In One Piece, does a Devil Fruit reappear after the user dies?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2979/in-one-piece-does-the-devil-fruit-reappear-after-the-user-dies)

In summary, when the ability user dies, the ability reborns in another fruit.

Comment: That is what he states. but his question is: "What happens when it gets destroyed". In other words he wants to know what happens if it gets destroyed for example by being thrown into the lava or that it will remain and sit on the bottom of it for the rest of time