# Can we share our devil fruit to someone else?

Tags: one-piece

For example, i have *gomu gomu no mi*. I already know that this is a devil fruit that whoever eat this fruit will gain a new power. I want someone of my crew/friend gain this ability too so i cut the fruit in half and at the same time we ate the fruit. Is this possible ? Did the author ever mention about this somewhere before ?

Comment: you can't https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/931/2869

Comment: thanx @Darjeeling